# Azure AD SSO with SAML Token encryption

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm working on SAML-based SSO with Azure AD.
I did all the required setup and able to make the SAMLRequest and able to get SAMLResponse on reply URL.
(Token encryption Menu imported Certificate (Base64) to encrypt the token.)
but the response is BASE64 encoded and encrypted.

I refered to below link.
[Manage certificates for federated single sign-on in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-certificates-for-federated-single-sign-on)

I decoded BASE64 then get xml Data.

### sample xml data

```
<samlp:Response ID="_8b8b42b6..........................xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sts.windows.net/.........../</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
             ......
             ......
             ......
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

---

**I want to decrypt attribute "EncryptedAssertion".**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the public key enclosed in the certificate , which is part of the IdP meta data to decrypt the EncryptedAssertion. You did not tell which SAML Service Provider (or SAML library) you are using though.

Comment: Thank you!
I have a question. 
I can download Certificate(base64) , Certificate(raw) and Federation metadata xml. 
I know Certificate(base64) is public key. 
If you can, I want you to tell me how to enclose with.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand your question. Federation meta data typically includes PEM-encoded certificate (without the PEM boundary).